# Create data frame, matching based on first elements of a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match

I want to create a data frame based on the first element of a list. Specifically, I have

One vector containing variables (names1);

One list that contains two variables (some vars1 and the values);

And the end product should a data.frame with "names1" that contains as many lines as cases that match.

If there is no match between a specific list and a the vector, it should be NA.

The values can also be factors or strings.

```
names1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
dat1 <- data.frame(names1 =c("a", "b", "c", "f"),values= c("val1", 13, 11, 0))
   dat1$values <- as.factor(dat1$values)
dat2 <- data.frame(names1 =c("a", "b", "x"),values= c(12, 10, 2))
   dat2$values <- as.factor(dat2$values)
list1 <- list(dat1, dat2)
```

The results should be a new data frame with the variables "names" and all values that match of each of list parts:

```
 a      b    c
 val1   13   11
 12     10   NA
```

Comment: A `data.table` solution: `library(data.table); rbindlist(lapply(list1, function(x) setNames(transpose(x)[2,], x$names)), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)[,.SD, .SDcols=(a:c)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to loop through the `list` ('list1'), `filter` the 'names' column based on the 'names' vector, convert it to a single dataset while creating an identification column with `.id`, `spread` from 'long' to 'wide' and remove the 'grp' column

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(list1, ~   .x %>% 
                     filter(names %in% !! names), .id = 'grp') %>%           
      spread(names, values) %>% 
      select(-grp)   
#      a     b     c    
#1    25    13    11
#2    12    10    NA
```

---

Or another option is to bind the datasets together with `bind_rows`, created a grouping id 'grp' to specify the `list` element, `filter` the rows by selecting only 'names' column that match with the 'names' `vector` and `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
bind_rows(list1, .id = 'grp') %>%
   filter(names %in% !! names) %>% 
   spread(names, values)
```

NOTE: It is better not to use reserved keywords for specifying object names (`names`).  Also, to avoid confusions, the object should be different from the column names of the dataframe object.

---

It can be also done with only `base R`.  Create a group identifier with `Map`, `rbind` the `list` elements to single dataset, `subset` the rows by keeping only the values from the 'names' `vector`, and `reshape` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
df1 <- subset(do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, list1, 
          ind = seq_along(list1))), names %in% .GlobalEnv$names)   
reshape(df1, idvar = 'ind', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'names')[-1]
```

Comment: Can one also do that for factors? (i.e., if values is a factor or a string?)

Comment: I realized it works, but only if not numeric values and factor values are mixed! Thanks so much, Akrun!!! Awesome!

Comment: @tobiassch  Thanks. That is a bit strange.  You could try `filter(as.character(names) %in% !! names)`

Answer (score 1):

A mix of base R and `dplyr`. For every list element we create a dataframe with 1 row. Using `dplyr`'s `rbind_list` row bind them together and then subset only those columns which we need using `names`.

```
library(dplyr)

rbind_list(lapply(list1, function(x) 
        setNames(data.frame(t(x$values)), x$names)))[names]

#     a     b     c
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    25    13    11
#2    12    10    NA
```

Output without subset looks like this

```
rbind_list(lapply(list1, function(x) setNames(data.frame(t(x$values)), x$names)))

#     a     b     c     x
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    25    13    11    NA
#2    12    10    NA     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R only

```
body <- do.call('rbind', lapply(list1, function(list.element){
  element.vals <- list.element[['values']]
  element.names <- list.element[['names']]
  names(element.vals) <- element.names
  return.vals <- element.vals[names]
  if(all(is.na(return.vals))) NULL else return.vals
}))

df <- as.data.frame(body)
names(df) <- names
df
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```
t(sapply(list1, function(x) setNames(x$values, names)[match(names, x$names)]))
#       a  b  c
# [1,] 25 13 11
# [2,] 12 10 NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works very well -- is there also a solution for factor values? (if values is a factor) ?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach using `dcast()` and `rowid()`:

```
library(data.table)
nam <- names1   # avoid name conflict with column name
rbindlist(list1)[names1 %in% nam, dcast(.SD, rowid(names1) ~ names1)][, names1 := NULL][]
```

> ```
>       a  b    c
> 1: val1 13   11
> 2:   12 10 <NA>
> ```

Or, more concisely, pick columns after reshaping:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list1)[, dcast(.SD, rowid(names1) ~ names1)][, .SD, .SDcols = names1]
```